# In Ember App Kit (EAK) how do you change the name of the application

Tags: ember.js

From the default:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create()
```

To:

```
var Something = Ember.Application.create()
```

I would like to know the proper place to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

Ember App Kit uses ES6 modules (future of JS programming). EAK makes use of [ES6 module transpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) to convert the ES6 syntax to AMD modules. **You need not probably stuff everything in the globals.**

The following [line](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/app/index.html#L114) in the `index.html` is where your Ember App gets boots up

```
window.Somthing = require('something/app')['default'].create(ENV.APP);
```

where `something` is the [modulePrefix](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/app/app.js#L5).